# Babel ES-Lint parse errors in imported module. Cannot find module './parse-with-patch'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, eslint

I have been searching Github and Stack Overflow for the past hour with no answer on how to fix this problem with ES-Lint.

[image]

**.eslintrc.json**

```
{
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "extends": ["airbnb", "prettier"],
  "plugins": ["prettier", "flowtype"],
  "rules": {
    "prettier/prettier": ["error"],
    "no-unused-expressions": 0,
    "react/jsx-filename-extension": 0,
    "class-methods-use-this": 0,
    "default-case": 0,
    "import/no-unresolved": 0,
    "react/prefer-stateless-function": 0,
    "import/no-named-as-default": 0
  },
  "parserOptions": {
    "sourceType": "module",
    "import/extensions": [".jsx", ".js"],
    "allowImportExportEverywhere": true
  }
}
```

**devDependencies**

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.1.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "eslint": "^5.7.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^17.1.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^3.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "^2.34.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.0.2",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.11.1",
    "flow-bin": "0.78.0",
    "jest": "23.5.0",
    "jest-react-native": "18.0.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.45.0",
    "prettier": "1.14.1",
    "react-native-debugger-open": "0.3.17",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
    "schedule": "0.4.0",
    "semver": "5.5.0"
  },
```

All of the linter options are working which is great, but there is no way I can let other people use this config if I am getting errors for every single import statement throughout the entire app.

Does anyone have any idea what could be going on?

Comment: Seeing same. Started happening after some updates today. It was either the update to Node 11 or just the general dependency updates. It isn't all of my imports, only the ones where I am importing a default export.

Comment: Are you using vs code?

Comment: No, IntelliJ. It might be Node. I'm not getting the error on TravisCI, which is still using Node 10.

Comment: I eliminated the Node version as the culprit. It looks like there might be some incompatibility with Babel 7.1. I had various other (serious) problems until I reverted my dependencies and got back to Babel 7.0. This ESLint issue also seems to be fixed now.

Comment: I fixed mine but I honestly dont remember what I did. Did you check to see if you had eslint installed in your global npm dependencies? It might be trying to use that version. I honestly don't remember what fixed my problem.

Comment: I don't have ESLint installed globally. I've got my project in a stable place right now, so I might try the dependency upgrades again to see what happens.

Answer (score 7):

These steps might work:

1. Change `path` to `path.ts`
2. Save
3. Again, change it to `path`
4. Save

Comment: This actually worked for me with error:

`Parse errors in imported module 'filename.ts': ',' expected.  import/namespace`

Wish i knew why... but now i'm just glad it's gone.

Answer (score 3):

Just disable that rule to rrsolve this issue insted of uninstalling ESLint

"Unfortunately, React + Redux is the most common scenario. However, there are lots of other cases where HOCs will force developers to shut down this rule."

https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/issues/544

https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/issues/119

https://github.com/18F/calc/pull/1235

.eslintrc

```
"rules": {
    "import/no-named-as-default": 0
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Deleting `node_modules` and reinstalling everything worked for me :-(

Answer (score 1):

just add in your eslint rules. Works fine for me

**"parser": "off",**

Answer (score 0):

`babel-eslint` has been deprecated. Update to `@babel/eslint-parser`.

https://tjaddison.com/blog/2021/03/updating-babel-eslint-to-babeleslint-parser-for-react-apps/

Comment: Please add  explanation with/or screen-capture or code. Sharing link over question may invalid after period of time, which tends to invalid answer.

Answer (score -7):

Uninstalling EsLint globally fixed my problem:
    `npm uninstall -g eslint`

Comment: Yeah, I think that should solve the problem for most people. Also, a really annoying gotcha is that I had to close and reopen VSCode before the settings took effect. Might be worthwhile for people to remove es lint globally then close and reopen their editor just in case.

Comment: Uninstalling EsLint is not a good practice. ESLint is used for ensuring code quality in the application. Uninstalling that not making any sense

Comment: Think people misunderstood this. I believe Alex meant uninstall the global version of eslint, and use the local version declared in the package.json.